# Scrolling div from a part of the sticky element

Tags: html, css, scroll, fixed

Scrolling div from a part of the sticky element. The below image demonstrates the book list which is scroll-able and the sticky div.

This image is with sticky div book going behind
[image]

This is normal state without sticky
[image]

I have used banner section below css code

[CODEPENLINK](https://codepen.io/soniajain/pen/KreGzJ)

```
<div class="banner_Section">abcd</div>
<div class="body_Section">mnop</div>

   .banner_Section {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
  background: url(https://www.dudleycourtpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/books.jpg) scroll no-repeat top center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 200px;
    }

.body_Section {margin: 200px 0 0 0; height: 400px; background: yellow;}
```

Fixed scrolling works but it gets behind after the banner section from white part.

The scrolling should happen from the bottom part of the image.

Comment: Please provide HTML and CSS both.

Comment: Do you want some like this? http://jsfiddle.net/apn7f2uz/

Comment: I want the bottom body_Section should scroll from bottom above image and than hide below image as seen in the image

Comment: I am not getting what are you talking about?

Comment: Check the edited question

Comment: Please try this:  .body_Section { position: relative; z-index: 1; }

Comment: https://codepen.io/soniajain/pen/oQyVRV Check here. Then it goes from top of image but need to go only party from top and than bottom of image

Comment: Please find the code below.